# Difference of execution time in same logic SOQL

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex, soql

I want to update Contact's Billing_Address__c field with Account's Billing_Address__c field whenever Account's Billing_Address__c is updated.
Set named as accIds already contains IDs of updated account. From two method of SOQL queries we can fetch contact and then update.

First >>>

`for(Contact con :  [Select Account.Billing_Address__c,Billing_Address__c FROM Contact where AccountID IN :accIds]){` and then updated each contact.

Second >>>

```
 for(Account acc :  [Select Billing_Address__c,(SELECT Billing_Address__c FROM Contacts) FROM Account where ID IN :accIds]){ 
       for(Contact con : acc.Contacts )
```

and then update contact . ***Is there any difference in execution time and if yes, which is faster ??***

Answer (score 1):

You should post this in Salesforce Stack, but ..

For the first one, execution time no not really.  But it does help with [managing heap size](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/08/16/managing-the-heap-in-salesforce-com/), but this question lost some context from the last post.  I wrote it like that because there was no reason for that extra list so it was saving 1 `List`

For the second one.. Why would you have 2 for loops? There is no reason for it in this case, and it would definitely not give you anymore speed.
You can test it for yourself by using the [Limits Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm)